# How to find the bottleneck on a virtual server?

Tags: ubuntu, virtualization, performance

I have purchased a cheap virtual server (running with Ubuntu, with 4 virtual? CPUs and guaranteed 8GB RAM, SSD). I started Tomcat8 with my web application (with -Xmx4096m). The startup time is very, very slow. It is about 50 times slower, then on my notebook. I would like to know what the bottleneck is. Is it CPU? Is ist the disk?

`top` or `htop` show me about 1% CPU usage and 300MB mem usage. Since it is a virtual server I have no idea if these are reliable. How can I check if I use up all the CPU given to me?

--- update ---

After stopping all services and starting tomcat alone, things got faster. the problem was mysql/php/tt-rss. But I still have no idea how this happened. Since CPU was at 1% I think it was the SSD. But where and how could I have seen this?

Comment: Can you add code to your startup scripts to output more information? Are there logs you can check?

Comment: Would the application be trying to access the internet?  With 1% cpu, you're maybe facing timeouts.  Check Tomcat's and the application's logs.  A  "tail -f" might show you where it's losing time.

Comment: Run "vmstat -2" and study the result - it should give you a good indication if the system is disk, io or CPU constrained.

Comment: You could use from your browser  "myip.ms"  website to find out how many sites are sharing your IP address.  There will be a line starting with a number 'live sites' and your IP address.  If you are sharing IP address with many sites, could your HOST provide a 'dedicated' site for a reasonable amount of $?

Comment: Post TEXT results of your TOP or HTOP report when you detect a bottleneck for analysis, please.